# How do I add a 64-bit Visio Drawing control in VS 2012?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, visio

We are using an embedded Visio drawing control in our application as an automated visualization tool to represent system heirarchies.  Code-behind uses Visio interop to create and lay out all of the shapes. The "designer" portion, with the embedded Visio document, is accomplished through a custom control that utilized the (ActiveX) Visio Drawing control within a WindowsFormsHost control.

This approach has worked well for several years, up to now.  We first implemented in VS2008/Visio 2007, then migrated to VS2010, and then Visio 2010.  Once we had moved to VS2010/O2010, we added another build targeted for x64.

To do this, I had to rebuild the ActiveX control. Since VS designer doesn't support the 64-bit version of the Visio Drawing control, you can't just simply create a WindowsFormsHost and drop the Visio Drawing control onto it; the WPF control has to be built differently from the way the 32-bit version is. I can't remember *exactly* how I did it, but I think it was basically this (possibly based on [this](http://www.techyv.com/questions/findind-drawing-control-microsoft-visio-2010-64-bit-version)):

1. Create a WPF form in a build environment with 32-bit Visio installed
2. Drag/drop the Visio Drawing control from the toolbox to the form, inside a WindowsFormsHost. Performing this step causes VS to create (and add a reference to) a new DLL, "Microsoft Visio 15.0 Drawing Control Type Library" of type AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx. This DLL is put into the /obj/Release directory under the project.
3. Build the project to create the WPF control DLL for the final x86 solution build
4. For your 32-bit solution, copy & reference both *{your control}*.dll *and* AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll.
5. Save, copy/move & open this control project in a build environment with 64-bit Visio installed
6. Change the build target to x64
7. Build the project to create the WPF control DLL for the final x64 solution build
8. Copy & reference /bin/Release/*{custom control}*.dll and /obj/Release/AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll.

I can build for the 32-bit version, but this doesn't work with Visio 2013 64-bit.  Any clue how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got our solution to work using 64-bit.

The magic was that I realized that I didn't actually need the control in the XAML; so what I ended up doing was removing the control from the XAML page, and instantiating it from the constructor of the .xaml.cs code.

So: follow the instructions in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx) to build a custom control. I *think* you have to build using the 64-bit version of MSBuild.exe as noted in [the link you provided](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980533).  This is apparently only required when you are creating the custom control; I was able to build the solution directly from VS (but it also worked correctly when built by MSBuild, so it works in automated builds, as well).

### Creating a custom control

1. Create a new custom control project named VisioAxControl in a build environment with 32-bit Visio installed
2. In VS Designer, drag/drop the Visio Drawing control from the toolbox to the form, inside a WindowsFormsHost. You may need to add this control to the toolbox (right-click toolbox, "Choose items...").  Performing this step causes VS to create (and add a reference to) a new DLL, "Microsoft Visio 15.0 Drawing Control Type Library" of type     AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx. This DLL is put into the /obj/Release directory under the project, but will be copied to /bin when you build if you simply select the reference and set "Copy local" to "true".
3. Open the code-behind and change the scope of the control to `public` and refactor:rename it from `axDrawingControl1` to `AxVisioControl` (most importantly, don't forget `this.AxVisioControl.Name = "AxVisioControl";`)
4. Build the project to create the WPF control DLL for the final x86/32-bit solution build
5. For your x86/32-bit solution, copy & reference both `VisioAxControl.dll` and `AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll` into a folder somewhere in the solution.

   #### Building the 64-bit control
6. Save, copy/move, and open the custom control project in a build environment with 64-bit Visio installed
7. Change the build platform to x64
8. Open an administrator command prompt, cd to your project directory
9. Run `MSBuild_Path\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 your_project_file_name` (for me, MSBuild_Path is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe) to build the custom control project to create the WPF control DLL for use in the final x64 solution build

### Including in your 64-bit project

1. Copy & reference `/bin/Release/VisioAxControl.dll` and `/obj/Release/AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll`.
2. In the XAML of your form, add a `<WindowsFormsHost name="MyWindowsFormsHost"></WindowsFormsHost>` control.
3. In the code-behind of the XAML, in the constructor:

   ```
   using VisioAxControl;
   public DesignView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       var avc = new VisioAxControl() { Name = "vControl" };
       this.MyWindowsFormsHost.Child = avc;
       this._avc = avc.AxVisioControl;  // for later reference, such as adding shapes
   }
   ```
4. Save & Build your project!